# Шукаємо вдалий переклад терміну Near-Critical Activity

Tags: from-english, терміни

"Перекладаємо PMBOK Lexicon та ISO Vocabulary в рамках проєкту ""PMBOK та PM ISO українською"". Намагаємося підбирати прості переклади, але такі, що передають сенс оригінальних англійських термінів.

Варіанти:

- близько-критична операція
- майже критична операція
- операція, близька до критичної
- потенційно критична операція

Визначення терміну Near-Critical Activity [там](https://wiki.friendsofcnm.org/en/Near-Critical_Activity%22) таке:

> **Near-Critical Activity.**  An activity with a total float that is deemed to be low based on expert judgment. See also critical path, free float, near-critical path, and total float.

Comment: Значення слова/словосполучення треба пояснювати так, щоб користувачу не доводилось переходити за посиланнями. Тут мені довелось це зробити, бо незрозуміло, що таке *total float*. Також необхідно перекладати, а не давати пояснення лише англійською.

Answer (score 1):

Словник [e2u подає](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=near-critical&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on):

> **near-critical** *a* майже критичний.
> **near-critical** ма́йже крити́чний, білякрити́чний, близьки́й до крити́чного зна́чення

Я б обрав *білякритична*, бо одним словом.

Answer (score 0):

Термін **критична діяльність** відноситься до будь-якої конкретної діяльності за розкладом, яка є частиною критичного шляху, який відбувається в межах графіку проекту.

**Критично-необхідна операція**

**Життєво необхідна діяльність**

**Ключовий процес життєзабезпечення**